# Which unit test framework for C can be used with Jenkins

Tags: c, jenkins, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am trying to find a unit test framework for C, that would work with Jenkins.
from the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C
i can see only few that generate results in XML , and gtest needs your code to be compiled with g++

I would appreciate if anyone has good experience using a test framework that worked well with Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in gtest the test classes have to be C++, but nobody prevents you from linking to C code. Therefore, the system under test can be written in C.

If it is ok that the test classes are in C++, gtest is a very viable option.